# Ruby on Rails: Custom Alphanumeric id based on another field and Auto increment it

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, auto-increment

Before starting I must say I'm new to Ruby on rails.

I have a model named Vendor. I want to have a field vendorid, which should be a alphanumeric field. I want to auto-increment it.

I also have a city, which is drop down select field in the same model. I want my vendorid to use that field in its value.

For example: If my first entry of Vendors has the city HYD, I would like my vendorid to be HYD001, If the next entry has city DEL, then vendorid should be DEL001, else if it has HYD as its city again then it should be HYD002.

Upon searching a lot on the web I found the gem **protokoll**. But I think even that does not help my situation.

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base    
    protokoll :vendorid, :pattern => city + "###"
end
```

I have also tried:

:pattern => "#{city}###"
:pattern => self.city + "###"

It throws me an error "undefined method `city' for #Class:0xb61c4150"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Protokoll looks like it would do what you want (i haven't used it myself though).  What's the problem with Protokoll?

Comment: I have edited the post by showing what I have done with protokoll and my results with that.

Comment: In your code, "city" is being used at the class level, when rails loads up.  It doesn't know what `city` is at that point.  It looks like you're trying to guess at the syntax for Protokoll, to tell it to use the city value instead of a fixed string.  This may not be possible but if it is then that's definitely not the right syntax.

Comment: same problem:  "self" is the class.  There's no `Vendor.city` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgetting about Protokoll for the moment, i think this should work.

```
class Vendor
  before_create :set_unique_vendorid

  def set_unique_vendorid
    if last_vendor = Vendor.find(:last, :order => "id", :conditions => ["vendorid like ?", "#{self.city}%"])
      last_vendorid_number = last_vendor.vendorid.scan(/\d+$/).first.to_i
      new_vendorid_number = last_vendorid_number + 1
    else
      new_vendorid_number = 1
    end
    self.vendorid = "#{self.city}#{sprintf("%03d", new_vendorid_number)}"
  end
```

the `sprintf` bit will convert new_vendorid_number into a three-digit string (eg "002") which it looked like you had as a requirement.

NOTE: you have a potential race condition here if you have a server running multiple instances of rails, and two of them try to create a new Vendor object at the same time.  But if you get to the point where you're so successful you need to worry about this then you can refactor it with transactions or something :O

Comment: Hi Max, Thanks a lot for that solution, I have been trying it on my own and did something similar to that of yours. I don't know If that is the right solution or not but it gives me correct answers. instead of last_ventorid_number I got the count like 
"count = Vendor.count(:conditions => ["city == ?", city])" and added 101 to it. Does this have any consequences? As I told you before I'm very new to all this.

Comment: Basing it on `count` doesn't guarantee uniqueness.  Eg: you make the first HYD vendor, it gets vendorid = "HYD101".  You make another in HYD, it gets vendorid = "HYD102".  You delete the first vendor. You make another vendor, it gets vendorid = "HYD102", because count = 1. You now have two vendors with the same vendorid.  With my approach each vendorid is always 1 higher than the last in that city.  Also they start at 001, which doesn't make people think there are already 100 other vendors in that city!

Comment: One more thing, in your method in the second line it should be **"last_vendorid_number = last_vendorid.vendorid.scan(/\d+$/).first.to_i"** . You missed out vendorid. It works fine now. Thanks again.

Comment: ah yes, sorry.  I would actually do it a little differently to your suggestion, which will break if it doesn't find a vendor.  I've edited my answer.